# How to get featured image in WP rest api

Tags: rest-api

I use below code for get last products from wp-json rest api

```
// Get posts via REST API.
function get_posts_via_rest() {
    $allposts = '';
    $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://mysite .com/product/wp-json/wp/v2/product?per_page=4' );
    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $posts = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
    if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            $allposts .= '<div class="jl_list_post_wrapper">
  <a href="' . esc_url( $post->link ) . '" class="jl_small_format feature-image-link image_post featured-thumbnail">
  <img src="'. esc_html( $post->featured_image_src) .'" class="attachment-disto_small_feature size-disto_small_feature wp-post-image"> <div class="background_over_image"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="item-details">
  <h3 class="feature-post-title"><a href="' . esc_url( $post->link ) . '">' . esc_html( $post->title->rendered ) . '</a></h3>
  <span class="post-meta meta-main-img auto_image_with_date">  <span class="post-date"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> in stock</span></span> </div>
</div>';
        }
        return $allposts;
    }
}
```

And also use below code for generating featured images in api

```
function post_featured_image_json( $data, $post, $context ) {
  $featured_image_id = $data->data['featured_media']; // get featured image id
  $featured_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $featured_image_id, 'original' ); // get url of the original size

  if( $featured_image_url ) {
    $data->data['featured_image_url'] = $featured_image_url[0];
  }

  return $data;
}
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_post', 'post_featured_image_json', 10, 3 );
```

But this is not working in my website.
Do you have any idea to get thumbnail product image?

And how to generate (in stock) / (out of stock) in api to show to other site?

Comment: When you say it does not work, what does it do instead?

Comment: @TomJNowell Hi tom, featured_image_url is not generated in my api.

Comment: you mean it is completely absent? Or it has a null/invalid value?

Comment: @TomJNowell With post_featured_image_json and without it, Nothing changes my api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add featured image to REST API by adding this code to your theme's functions.php

```
// Add featured image to REST API
add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_rest_images' );
function register_rest_images(){
    register_rest_field( array('post'),
        'fimg_url',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'get_rest_featured_image',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}
function get_rest_featured_image( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
    if( $object['featured_media'] ){
        $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $object['featured_media'], 'app-thumb' );
        return $img[0];
    }
    return false;
}
```

You should then see the url of the featured image under fimg_url.

Comment: I added this code to my functions.php but Nothing changed. https://imgur.com/a/0lYTX3v

Comment: that's because the code is for post type of "post". you seem to be using a custom post type.

Comment: Yes I am using WC (product post type)

Comment: Did it work? I think there's an extra bracket next to array('post')