# How to get a page's featured image through REST API?

Tags: post-thumbnails, rest-api

The featured image of a post/page is *not* included when using REST API. Not only that, getting it is not particularly simple. This seemingly irrational fact apart, I tried to implement [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/386629/11634) but when fetching my page through `/wp/v2/pages/?slug=my-page-name` I see no new field for the featured image.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because the *custom REST field (`fimg_url`)* was only being added to *posts of the `post` type* and yet your request was for Pages, i.e. posts of the `page` type.. so try changing the [`register_rest_field( array('post')`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/386629/137402) to `register_rest_field( array('post', 'page')`.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/#parameters.

But actually, you can use the [`_embed` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/#_embed) to have the full media object be **embedded** into the response of your post/page request.

Example using JavaScript's `window.fetch`:

```js
fetch( '/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?_embed' )
//fetch( '/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?_embed=wp:featuredmedia' ) // This also works.
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( posts => {
        posts.map( ( post ) => {
            const media = post._embedded?.['wp:featuredmedia']?.[0];

            // Default sizes, which are also the keys in mediaSizes are: full,
            // medium and thumbnail.
            const mediaSizes = media?.media_details?.sizes || {};

            console.log( mediaSizes.thumbnail?.source_url, mediaSizes );
            // Hint: Just log the `post` and `media` to see what properties are
            // there.
        } );
    } );
```

The above can reduce the number of HTTP requests, but it can also increase the response size, so you might *instead* want to use the [`featured_media` property](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#schema) to request the media object via the [`GET /wp/v2/media/<id>` endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/#retrieve-a-media-item). E.g.

```js
function getFeaturedMedia( mediaId ) {
    return fetch( '/wp-json/wp/v2/media/' + mediaId ).then( res => res.json() );
}

fetch( '/wp-json/wp/v2/pages' )
    .then( res => res.json() )
    .then( posts => {
        posts.map( async ( post ) => {
            const media = post.featured_media ?
                await getFeaturedMedia( post.featured_media ) : null;

            // Default sizes, which are also the keys in mediaSizes are: full,
            // medium and thumbnail.
            const mediaSizes = media?.media_details?.sizes || {};

            console.log( mediaSizes.thumbnail?.source_url, mediaSizes );
        } );
    } );
```

Comment: PS: Sorry, I forgot to rename the `getFeaturedMedia` function, e.g. to `restGetMediaItem`..